# drRacket structure error

Tags: racket

When I write these codes and program gives error;

```
"leaf-name: expects a leaf, given empty"

(define-struct leaf (parent children name level-of-vertex))
(define A (make-leaf empty '(B C D) 'A 1))
(define B (make-leaf A '(E F) 'B 2))
(define C (make-leaf A 'G 'C 2))
(define D (make-leaf A '(H J) 'D 2))
(define E (make-leaf B empty 'E 3))
(define F (make-leaf B '(K L) 'F 3))
(define G (make-leaf C empty 'G 3))
(define H (make-leaf D empty 'H 3))
(define J (make-leaf D empty 'J 3))
(define K (make-leaf F empty 'K 4))
(define L (make-leaf F empty 'L 4))
(define binarytree (list A B C D E F G H J K L empty))
(define (findchild child)
  (display (leaf-name (leaf-children child))))
(findchild E)
```

How I can solve this error?

Comment: what errors , what are you trying to do with this program?

Comment: the error is "leaf-name: expects a leaf, given empty"

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
(define binarytree (list A B C D E F G H J K L empty))
```

to

```
(define binarytree (list A B C D E F G H J K L))
```

After the above change, note that that:

```
(define E (make-leaf B empty 'E 3))
```

Thus

> (leaf-children E)
>       empty

That's why (leaf-name (leaf-children E))) becomes (leaf-name empty) and you get the error.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :(

I think the problem is with lists where I defined top,

the problem is not with only empty, when I tried (findchild A) the error is "leaf-name: expects a leaf, given (list 'B 'C 'D)"  if I remove ' this, the error is "B is used here before its definition"

I couldn't put them the correct order

Answer (score 0):

I imagine `(leaf-children node)` would evaluate to a list of objects and not a `leaf`. In fact, `E` doesn't have children.

When you select parent you use an actual object, but with children you have quotes list of symbols as children. Thus they are not a list of objects but symbols.

Without mutation you can either point upward or downward. With both you need to do one then the other by mutation. Perhaps from leaf to root. The `binarytree` is strange since I'd guess the full binary tree is supposed to be `A`.